# Can I do a monthly automatic bill by code in paypal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to do [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/manage-billing-plans/) but by code each month. (by curl for example)

I only have ID profile: I-************
Is possible? I can't find the way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this with recurring payment. For your case, you can actually use reference transaction to bill your customer each month. You will need to call for reference transaction API each month using curl.

Refer this documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ec_set_up_reference_transactions/